# What allows diverse ecology to thrive despite forces reducing species diversity?

Tags: ecology, theoretical-biology, modeling

Ecology and business are a useful model for understanding one another. One species fills a niche until it is outcompeted by another just as one business fills a niche until it is outcompeted by another. Businesses adopt successful strategies and traits from others, roughly akin to horizontal gene transfer, and fail should they become no longer able to compete.

The breakdown of this duality reveals interesting questions about differences between the two where one would expect similarities. One big example of this, and the topic of this question, concerns the trend of de-diversification in business. Over time, competitive industries tend toward a decrease in number of companies (species) filling a niche, with major shocks (like COVID-19) tending to cause smaller businesses to go extinct, and the strengthening of bigger players. Once a powerful oligopoly is established, it is almost impossible to overturn.

Yet in Earth's history, there have been countless major and minor extinction events, and countless highly successful species dominant in their niche that have been successfully displaced by smaller, newer competitors. Why is it that new competitors can compete with entrenched incumbents in biology, maintaining species diversity in biology where it fails in business?

Comment: You are incorrect about the business part of this, as there are numerous examples of near-monopoly businesses being displaced by new competitors.  For instance, the US "Big Three" automakers losing market dominance to foreign companies, on-line retailers taking market share away from malls, cell phones replacing land lines...  And have you tried to buy an incandescent light bulb lately?

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here. I'll try to leave an answer later. I'll share one initial observation: You seem to strongly emphasize the inmpact of competition or competative exclusion, perhaps because it's so ingrained in the philosophy of capitalism. But there are a number of factors that go into determining diversity in an ecosystem besides just competition. Related keywords: Niche partitioning, cross-feeding, mutualism, community succession, niche construction, intermediate disturbance hypothesis.

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Comment: I agree with jamesqf. It is not at all clear to me that ecology and business show any fundamental differences based on the information that you've presented, which is only a series of assertions. If jamesqf's counterfactuals are insufficient to convince you, it would be helpful to understand why not. If you have such information, it would be helpful to share it or link to it if you want a meaningful answer to the question.